# Multiple line anchor tags including span tag

Tags: html, css

I've got an anchor tag with multiple lines of text and at the beginning a span tag which includes an iconfont. Now I want to have all lines of text to be on the same intend. How can I achieve this?

[image]

HTML-Code:

```html
<div class="controlls">
  <p class="catalogue-pdf">
    <a href="http://www.google.com/" class="text-link" target="_blank"><span class="icon-pdf"></span> PDF download</a>
    <span class="separation-point">·</span> 82,0 kB
  </p>

  <p class="catalogue-link">
    <a href="http://www.google.com/" class="text-link" target="_blank"><span class="icon-book"></span> Stack Overflow Question Two Line Texts</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `clear:both` to the icon class?

Comment: you mean to the .icon-pdf and .icon-book? seems not to be working ...

Comment: add your CSS to the example code you have given so that people can look at it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this about what you're going for?

HTML:

```
<p class="catalogue-link">
    <a href="http://www.google.com/" class="text-link" target="_blank">
        <span class="icon-book"></span> 
        <span class="link-text">Stack Overflow Question Two Line Texts</span>
    </a>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.catalogue-link a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.catalogue-link .link-text {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
```